# Trying to setState using react hooks but what I get is an empty array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-state

As u can prolly see I'm fairly new to React.js. Here, I'm trying to create a todo list application. It should have three buttons on top - one for showing completed tasks, second for incompleted ones and the last one showing all the tasks on the list. So, i need two lists - one for every item added to the list and another one for filtering i guess. The thing is I cannot grasp the state thing in this situation and my filter array is empty. I don't want to mutate state directly but tried many things and I have to do sth wrong. Here's the code for the first button.

I want to click on the button, rerender the site and have the list of filtered items.

```
 //todos, setTodos are for my primary state

 const TodoFilter = ({ todos, setTodos}) => {

 const [filter, setFilter] = useState([])

 const handleActive = () => {
 const allTodos = [...todos]

 const completedFilter = allTodos.filter(item => item.isComplete === true)   

 setFilter(completedFilter)

 }
```

Comment: `const handleActive = () => ` isn't valid JS

Comment: Yeah, don't know why but something cut the part of the code.

Comment: From a code / syntax perspective, it looks fine. (Apart from the missing closing bracket still, for your handleActive function).  You may be better putting up more code, or a runnable snippet / jsfiddle

Comment: Also, you don't need to spread `todos` to create `allTodos` as `Array.prototype.filter()` returns a new array anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing quite a lot, so not sure if this is everything you coded so far or you haven't included some other bits. You need to add a checkbox to check the completed todos before clearing them.

Please try below code to filter completed todos from incompleted todos and assuming you have a button to clear it. Hope this helps

```
function handleCleartodos() {
const completedFilter = allTodos.filter(item => !item.isComplete)
setFilter(completedFilter)
}

<button onClick={handleCleartodos}>Clear Todos</button>
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect that to do differently? `filter` does not alter the original array, so changing to this code will trigger a re-render with no state change.

Comment: Yeah, I have just posted a small part of my code since i have 4 components. The thing is I tried your way before u posted it but the state doesnt change since I have two different states to toggle. I guess thanks to async nature of that useState()

I need to copy the content from todos to filter via setFilter and make filter to show itself instead of rendering todos :D Kinda messy i guess :D